# What is the Scala equivalent of Java's ClassName.class?

Tags: scala

How do I get an instance of `Class` in Scala? In Java, I can do this:

```
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;
```

What would be the equivalent in Scala?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There is a method [classOf](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#classOf[T]:Class[T]) in `scala.Predef` that retrieves the runtime representation of a class type.

```
val stringClass = classOf[String]
```

You can use the `getClass` method to get the class object of an instance at runtime in the same manner as Java

```
scala> val s = "hello world"
s: String = hello world

scala> s.getClass
res0: Class[_ <: String] = class java.lang.String
```