# How can I easily get a Scala case class's name?

Tags: scala, class, classname

Given:

```
case class FirstCC {
  def name: String = ... // something that will give "FirstCC"
}
case class SecondCC extends FirstCC
val one = FirstCC()
val two = SecondCC()
```

How can I get `"FirstCC"` from `one.name` and `"SecondCC"` from `two.name`?

Comment: Doesn't the toString method of case classes have their name (and parameters)?

Comment: `FirstCC.toString` returns `"<function>"`

Comment: Through you probably meant `one.toString`...

Comment: A better solution appears on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166732/what-is-the-scala-equivalent-of-javas-classname-class

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
def name = this.getClass.getName
```

Or if you want only the name without the package:

```
def name = this.getClass.getSimpleName
```

See the documentation of [java.lang.Class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more information.

Comment: Note, however, that `getSimpleName` can sometimes throw `java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name`, for instance when calling it on the class of an object.

Comment: Since 1.5 you can also use `getCanonicalName`

Comment: getSimpleName and getCannonicalName are still buggy, there is an ongoing ticket. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034 (and it's closed-as-duplicate issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5425)

Comment: also note that for `case class \`First-CC\`` you will get the simple name this: `First$minusCC` which you'll need to normalize to make it match the actual name again

Answer (score 27):

You can use the property `productPrefix` of the case class:

```
case class FirstCC {
  def name = productPrefix
}
case class SecondCC extends FirstCC
val one = FirstCC()
val two = SecondCC()

one.name
two.name
```

N.B.
If you pass to scala 2.8 extending a case class have been deprecated, and you have to not forget the left and right parent `()`

Answer (score 16):

```
class Example {
  private def className[A](a: A)(implicit m: Manifest[A]) = m.toString
  override def toString = className(this)
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of this (2.8-only) approach over `this.getClass.getName`?

Comment: @pr1001 It will preserve type parameters if you have them.

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve class name without package part from that (just as in case of `getSimpleName`)? I find your answer very nice way to overcome `java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name` exception in case of nested objects

Comment: This also ensures that type ``Foo-Bar-Gong`` (with back-ticks) renders as "Foo-Bar-Gong" (as of 2.11.6)

Answer (score 11):

```
def name = this.getClass.getName
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `getName`. Much better than `toString`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Scala function that generates a human-readable string from any type, recursing on type parameters:

https://gist.github.com/erikerlandson/78d8c33419055b98d701

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object TypeString {

  // return a human-readable type string for type argument 'T'
  // typeString[Int] returns "Int"
  def typeString[T :TypeTag]: String = {
    def work(t: Type): String = {
      t match { case TypeRef(pre, sym, args) =>
        val ss = sym.toString.stripPrefix("trait ").stripPrefix("class ").stripPrefix("type ")
        val as = args.map(work)
        if (ss.startsWith("Function")) {
          val arity = args.length - 1
          "(" + (as.take(arity).mkString(",")) + ")" + "=>" + as.drop(arity).head
        } else {
          if (args.length <= 0) ss else (ss + "[" + as.mkString(",") + "]")
        }
      }
    }
    work(typeOf[T])
  }

  // get the type string of an argument:
  // typeString(2) returns "Int"
  def typeString[T :TypeTag](x: T): String = typeString[T]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def name = getClass.getSimpleName.split('$').head
```

This will remove the `$1` appearing at the end on some classes.

Comment: I found a better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204470/378070). Basically using Scala's reflection instead of Java's, will solve the issue. I did like this: `classOf[Int].getSimpleName`. This solves the issue of $ at the end.

Comment: That's a good solution too, but if you are running that on a Trait maybe you don't know which type has `this` so you don't know what to put inside `classOf[]`