# Creating a UDF in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, geomesa

I am trying to create a permanent function in spark using geomesa-spark-jts.
Geomesa-spark-jts has huge potential in the larger LocationTech community. 
I started first by downloading geomesa-spark-jts which contain the following

[image]

The after that I have launched spark like this (I made sure that the jar is within the path)

[image]

Now whew I use ST_Translate which come with that package, it does give me a result

[image]

But the problem is when I try to define ST_Translate as a UDF , I get the following error

[image]

Comment: This is strange indeed. Did you try using sqlContext.udf.register instead? I think this could be because of where it is looking for this class. The jar is added to the driver process but not to the executors. I had some weird errors like this when I was using a specific version of spark-llap I think..

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?  GeoMesa 2.0.0 works with Spark 2.2.0.  We haven't tested it with Spark 2.3.0.

Comment: Also, as a note, you mentioned using version 2.0.0-m1, and then your screenshot has version 2.0.0 and 1.3.0.  I'd suggest cleaning up your classpath and just using version 2.0.0.

Comment: @SubramaniamRamasubramanian I didn't use sqlContext.udf.register bescause at some point I have to prise the type of the input or output but in both cases its a Geometry type which isn't known to Spark

Comment: Also, what's the function you are interested in adding?  If it a common geospatial function, it might be easiest to contribute to GeoMesa;).

Comment: @GeoMesaJim the function that I interested in is ST_Translate and ST_MakeLine and ST_MakePolygon

Comment: ST_Translates isn't a class, it's a member variable: https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-spark/geomesa-spark-jts/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/spark/jts/udf/SpatialRelationFunctions.scala#L24

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz I you use esri geometry api and you do this sqlContext.sql("""create temporary function st_point as 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.ST_Point'"""); your are able to create a function, and that is the same thing that I want to do here

Comment: From what I can tell, `create temporary function` is tied to hive. ST_Point is an actual class that extends `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF`. It may not be possible to do what you want. At the least, it would seem to require some additional integration work in spark-jts

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz Yes, you are Hive lack some functions such as ST_Translate. And I need that function

Comment: so you are trying to use st_translate with hive?

Comment: @EmilioLahr-Vivaz Yes, exactly, if you have any idea how to do so please help me, I'm desperate.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you mentioned are already supported in GeoMesa 2.0.0 for Spark 2.2.0.  http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/sparksql_functions.html

Comment: I know they are already in geomesa since I'm using geomesa-spark-jts jar

Comment: Mea culpea.  It's early for me; I missed that you are trying to use the 'create temporary function' call.  The FQCN for the function is likely something like org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts.udf.SpatialRelationFunctions$.ST_Translate.  The $ (or something like that it) is needed to reference the Scala object SpatialRelationFunctions.  That might do it...

Comment: Yes that's what I would like to do, can you elaborate your point more.

Comment: Of course!  It looks like Spark needs the classname to try and register a new function name.  The complete classname for the function is different from what you used (hence the JVM complaining that it could not find the class).

If you try out the $ at the end of SpatialRelationFunctions in that call, it may work.

Scala adds a dollar sign to the end of the Scala object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570148/why-does-scala-place-a-dollar-sign-at-the-end-of-class-names

Comment: Even with the dollar added I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The `geomesa-accumulo-spark-runtime` jar is a shaded jar that includes the code from `geomesa-spark-jts`. You might be hitting issues with having the classes defined in two different jars.

Comment: So you suggest removing geomesa-accumulo-spark-runtime from the path ?

Comment: yes, remove one or the other. if you're just using the jts bindings, then remove the accumulo jar. if you want the additional geotools functionality, then remove the jts jar (it will still be present in the accumulo jar)

Comment: when I removed geomesa-accumulo-spark-runtime from the path and I did " import org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts._ "  I got this erro error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SpatialEncoders.class'.

Comment: you will also need jts on the classpath - com.vividsolutions:jts-io,com.vividsolutions:jts-core,org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j and possibly transitive dependencies of theirs. it may be simpler to use the accumulo-spark-runtime jar instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `st_translate` with hive, I believe that you would have to implement a new class that extends `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF` and invokes the GeoMesa function.

Comment: I think so too, but I don't know how to implement that !