# How to get the concrete class for a mixed in trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding

Say I have the following traits and classes:

```
trait A {
    def foo(): Unit
}

trait B extends A {
    abstract override def foo(): Unit = {
        // Can I determine the name of the concrete class here?
        super.foo()
    }
}

class C extends A {
    def foo() = {
        println("C::foo()")
    }
}

val c = new C with B
c.foo()
```

Is there a way from within trait B that I can determine the name for the concrete class in which it has been instantiated? i.e. C

Comment: *Is there a way from within trait B that I can determine the name for the concrete class in which it has been instantiated? i.e. C* `B` is not instantiated in `C`.

Comment: Did you mean `val c = new C with B`?

Comment: Well, I believe you can call `this.getClass.getName` however, why do you want to have the class name? What do you want to do with that information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I easily get a Scala case class's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656364/how-can-i-easily-get-a-scala-case-classs-name)

Comment: Frankly, this just sounds like a bad idea to start with. If your traits need to know about the classes that extend them, then your design is broken.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt, I disagree with you in that specific case. Usually this scenario is very common for logging. You place the mutual code in a trait, but when reading the logs it is very important to know who is the final actor.

Comment: But the ”final actor“ is not C in this case, it's an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.getClass.getSuperclass.getSimpleName`

```
trait A {
  def foo(): Unit
}

trait B extends A {
  abstract override def foo(): Unit = {
    println("B is instantiated in " + getClass.getSuperclass.getSimpleName)
    super.foo()
  }
}

class C extends A {
  def foo() = {
    println("C::foo()")
  }
}

val c = new C with B
c.foo()
//B is instantiated in C
//C::foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's modify your code a bit, as it does not compile. When calling super.foo from B, you get an exception since it is not implemented.

```
package test

object HelloWorld1 {
  trait A {
    def foo(): Unit
  }

  trait B extends A {
    override def foo(): Unit = {
      println(getClass.getName)
      // Can I determine the name of the concrete class here?
    }
  }

  class C extends B {  }

  class D extends B { }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val c = new C
    c.foo()
    val d = new D
    d.foo()
  }
}
```

Given that code, you can call getClass.getName which will provide a string, constructed from the full package name, and class of the current.

In the given example, you'll get:

```
test.HelloWorld1$C
test.HelloWorld1$D
```

If you take classes C and D, outside of HelloWorld1, you'll get:

```
C
D
```

If you want to get only `C` and `D` in the first option, i.e. inside HelloWorld1, you can call to `getClass.getSimpleName` instead of `getClass.getName`

There is another option. You can also use `getClass.getCanonicalName` which will replace the `$` with `.`.