# What is Scala's analog for Java's class literal, e.g. Foo.class?

Tags: scala

In Java I would write `logger.getLogger(NameOfClass.class)`. How to write the same in Scala?

Comment: Why do you call it *binary*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Scala equivalent of Java's ClassName.class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166732/what-is-the-scala-equivalent-of-javas-classname-class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
logger.getLogger(getClass())
```

or:

```
logger.getLogger(classOf[NameOfClass])
```

As a side note, [ScalaLogging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scalalogging) provides a nice and easy way to use a logger with the class name but without all of the boilerplate like normal java. You get a logger in your class setup properly and all you have to do is extend a trait `Logging`:

```
class MyClass extends Logging {
  logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")
}
```

Comment: But then you have to add a trait wherever you want logging? That seems like worse boilerplate to me.

Comment: But you don't have to do 'val logger = logger.getLogger(NameOfClass.class)' or 'if (logger.isDebugEnabled)' etc... so it's less boilerplate which is better :)

Comment: @david explicitly creating logger every time isn't boilerplate?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I didn't say that did I? I just think I would rather create a val than clutter up my class hierarchy. They are both boilerplate.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea when I want to use another log tool, @david. The extends kind of method just pollute the classes I create, and the logic class should be isolated with logging tool

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to define the logger on the singleton companion object:

```
object MyClass {
    // Commons logging
    private val clLogger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass())

    // java.util.logging
    private val juLogger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString)

}

class MyClass {
    import MyClass._

    ...
}
```

The reason one should do this is that if you place the field on the `class` it's an instance field which goes back to the logger factory on every `new` instance of an object of that class. This can be unnecessary/unacceptable performance for some classes.

Scala's separation of the class (static) fields and instance fields, in this case, makes this much more arduous than would be done with Java.  One of those cases where Scala doesn't have all the advantages:

```
class MyClass {
    // Commons logging
    private static final Log clLogger = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class)

    // java.util.logging
    private static final Logger juLogger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.toString)

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a little weird, just for a few static fields, and I have define another more class...

Comment: It's clumsy, but the alternative introduces run time overhead (log factory) on each `new` of a class instance.